# How to print ASCII value of a character using basic awk only

Tags: unix, shell, awk

I need to print the ASCII value of the given character in awk only.

Below code gives `0` as output:

```
echo a | awk '{ printf("%d \n",$1); }'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

see the awk manual for [ordinal functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ordinal-Functions.html) you can use. But since you are using awk, you should be on some version of shell, eg bash. so why not use the shell?

```
$ printf "%d" "'a"
97
```

Answer (score 35):

Using only basic awk (not even gawk, so the below should work on all BSD and Linux variants):

```
$ echo a | awk 'BEGIN{for(n=0;n<256;n++)ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=n}{print ord[$1]}'
97
```

Here's the opposite direction (for completeness):

```
$ echo 97 | awk 'BEGIN{for(n=0;n<256;n++)chr[n]=sprintf("%c",n)}{print chr[$1]}'
a
```

Basic premise is to use a lookup table.

Comment: Good one! Note you can directly say `echo 97 | awk '{printf("%c", $1)}'` and get `a`.

Comment: They even handle NUL correctly. (Test the first one using `printf '\0'`)

Answer (score 6):

It seems this is not a trivial problem. I found this approach using a lookup array, which should work for A-Z at least:

```
 BEGIN { convert="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" } 
       { num=index(convert,substr($0,2,1))+64; print num }
```

Comment: for this solution to work i need to create lookup array for all the characters in the ASCII table in the order.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It's only 127 values though, so it's not that big a deal.