# Convert alphabets to numbers and remove numbers before a colon

Tags: unix, awk, converters

I have a data that are alphabetic in some columns and have colon denoting the attribute number. How can I convert the alphabets (single capital alphabets) to numbers, A to 1, B to 2 ... Z to 26 and also remove the colons and number before the colons in each column. For example,

```
A,1:2.33,2:3.18
M,1:8.72,2:7.25
Y,1:9.55,2:3.43
C,1:5.78,2:4.32
```

I want to convert this to

```
1,2.33,3.18
13,8.72,7.25
25,9.55,3.43
3,5.78,4.32
```

There is no colon in first column and there are no alphabets after the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk` to convert text to number like with this command:

```
split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",a,"")
```

So you can get some like this:

```
awk -F":|," 'BEGIN {split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",a,"");for (i=1;i<=27;i++) x[a[i]]=i} {print x[$1],$3,$5}' OFS=, file
1,2.33,3.18
13,8.72,7.25
25,9.55,3.43
3,5.78,4.32
```

It makes an array with `a[1]=A a[2]=B` etc, then convert it so `x[A]=1 x[B]=2 etc`
Split the data by `:` and `,` then convert first column from text to value and print the rest.

Using `google` would help to solve this: [How to print ASCII value of a character using basic awk only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499270/how-to-print-ascii-value-of-a-character-using-basic-awk-only)

---

To handle multiple column:

```
awk -F":|," 'BEGIN {split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",a,"");for (i=1;i<=27;i++) x[a[i]]=i} {printf "%s,",x[$1];for (i=3;i<NF;i+=2) printf "%s,",$i;print $NF}' OFS=, file
```

Comment: I knew the conversion bit, but since I was asking the second part, I asked the first one, just to know if there exists something more trivial in awk. The splitting the array bit did not come to mind, and I have a question for you. How can I extend this to a data that has 100 or more columns. In general is there any way to print every alternate row? Thanks !!

Comment: @lovedynasty if you have many columns with `:`, and you want to remove, you can consider to use `gsub()`. for example extending @kent's solution `awk -F, 'BEGIN{..}{$1=ord[$1];gsub(/,[0-9]+:/,",")}1' file` (or I should use the `7` instead of `1` here?) :-)

Comment: @Imagination `7` and `1` does the same. A number gives default `true` and will do the default action, print.

Answer (score 3):

Jotne's `ABCD...Z` solution works, but I would post another more general(hopefully) solution:

```
awk -F '[,:]' -v OFS="," 'BEGIN{for(n=65;n<100;n++)ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=++x}
{print ord[$1],$3,$5}' file
```

The trick is in the `BEGIN` block. here I limited it, so that only `[A-Z]` will be acceptable, which may enough for your questions. But if you have other chars (like all chars in ascii), or you want to return other index logic, like `A->5, B->6...` or `a-97,b-98...A-65, B-66...` you can just change the `n` and the `x` in above one-liner.