# Use SED Regex to replace certain letters with numbers

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

After something I guess is pretty complex, and I am pretty bad with regex's so you guys might be able to help.

See this data source:

```
User ID:    
a123456
a12345f
a1234e6
d123d56
b12c456
c1b3456
ba23456
```

Basically, what I want to do, is use a regex/sed to replace all occurances of letters into numbers EXCEPT the first letter. Letters will always match their alphabet position. e.g. a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 etc.

So the result set should look like this:

```
    User ID:
    a123456
    a123456
    a123456
    d123456
    b123456
    c123456
    b123456
```

There will also never be any letters other that a-j, and the string will always be 7 chars long.

Can anyone shed some light? Thanks! :)

Comment: I would play with `awk` around  using empty `FS` and the mapping done in [How to print ASCII value of a character using basic awk only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14223031/1983854)

Comment: Are you sure that you have seven characters all the time in the input ?

Comment: Yes - always 7. They are user ID's. It will never we greater than 7 (including the initial letter).

Comment: which letter is 0, and can letters stand for numbers larger than 9 (i.e., with several digits)?

Comment: J = 0, and no, only numbers 0-9 are used, and letters simply replace their number counterpart, so there will never be a latter greater than j.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you could do it using standard tools `cut`, `paste` and `tr`:

```
$ paste -d'\0' <(cut -c1 file) <(cut -c2- file | tr 'abcdef' '123456')
a123456
a123456
a123456
d123456
b123456
c123456
b123456
```

This joins the first character of the line with the result of `tr` on the rest of the line, using the null string. `tr` replaces each element found in the first list with the corresponding element of the second list.

Answer (score 3):

To replace `a-j` letters in a line by the corresponding digits except the first letter using `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 'substr($_, 1) =~ tr/a-j/0-9/' input_file
```

`a=0`, not `a=1` because `j` would be `10` (two digits) otherwise.

> J = 0, and no, only numbers 0-9 are used, and letters simply replace their number counterpart, so there will never be a latter greater than j.

To make `j=0` and `a=1`:

```
$ perl -pe 'substr($_, 1) =~ tr/ja-i/0-9/' input_file
```

Comment: It looks like the desired behaviour is a=1, b=2, ..., j=0 but the approach looks good otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/[a-j][0-9a-j]\{6\}$/{h;y/abcdefghij/1234567890/;G;s/.\(.\{6\}\).\(.\).*/\2\1/;}' YourFile
```

- filter on "number" only
- remind line (for 1st letter)
- change all letter to digit (including 1st)
- add first form of number (as second line in buffer)
- take 1st letter of second line and 6 last of 1st one, reorder and dont keep the other character

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} NR>1{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if(p=index("jabcdefghi",$i)) $i=p-1} 1' file
User ID:
a123456
a123456
a123456
d123456
b123456
c123456
b123456
```

Note that the above reproduces the header line `User ID:` as-is. So far, best I can tell, all of the other posted solutions would change the header line to `Us5r ID:` since they would do the letter-to-number translation on it just like on all of the subsequent lines.

Comment: i was trying to search how to separate each letter as field, trying just FS, seems OFS is also needed to achieve this. Well done

Comment: Setting FS to null separates the input into characters, but assigning a value to any field re-compiles the record ($0) using the value of OFS so setting OFS to null is also required so that when $0 is recompiled there's nothing between the chars.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the complexity. Your samples look like you just want to replace six of seven characters with the numbers 1-6:

```
s/^\([a-j0-9]\)[a-j0-9]\{6\}/\1123456/
```

Since the numbers to put there are defined by position, we don't care what the letter was (or even if it was a letter). The downside here is that we don't preserve the numbers, but they never varied in your sample data.

If we want to replace only letters, the first method I can think of involves simply using multiple substitutions:

```
s/^\([a-j0-9]\{1\}\)[a-j]/\11/
s/^\([a-j0-9]\{2\}\)[a-j]/\12/
s/^\([a-j0-9]\{3\}\)[a-j]/\13/
s/^\([a-j0-9]\{4\}\)[a-j]/\14/
s/^\([a-j0-9]\{5\}\)[a-j]/\15/
s/^\([a-j0-9]\{6\}\)[a-j]/\16/
```

Replacing letters with specific digits, excluding the first letter:

```
s/\(.\)a/\11/g
```

This pattern will replace two character sequences, preserving the first, so would have to be run twice for each letter. Using hold space we could store the first character and use a simple transliteration. The tricky part is joining the two sections, whereupon sed injects an unwanted newline.

```
# Store in hold space
h
# Remove the first character
s/^.//
# Transliterate letters
y/jabcdefghi/0123456789/
# Exchange pattern and hold space
x
# Keep the first character
s/^\(.\).*$/\1/
# Print it
#P
# Join
G
# Remove the newline
s/^\(.\)./\1/
```

Still learning about sed's capabilities :)

Comment: My sample data might have been a bit bad. The user IDs will vary. e.g. a743195, d326578, d918222. These could have IDs represented as d91822b/d9182b2, d918b22,d91h222, d9a8222, dj18222. Etc.

Comment: @StevenFalzon yes your sample data is bad. You always show exactly the same output for every input set and you have 1 letter that's to be treated differently from all the rest, j, and you don't even include that in your example. Edit your question so your example helps show your problem.