# How character \ result in different outputs when to call bash in awk--Shell Expansions and Quote Removal?

Tags: bash, awk, quote, expansion

To convert decimal 32 into it's hex value with printf.

```
printf '%x\n'  32
20
```

The right awk statement to call the above bash in awk is as below.

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '\''%x\n'\''  32")}'
20
```

My question has no relationship with that.
For the following call bash in awk,where is the \?
Character **`\`** lost,why?

```
~$ awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n'  32")}'
20n~$
```

**\n** is not parsed as newline ,nor **\n literally**,but **n** only ,why parser lost it--the **`\`**?
To make my question more clear,

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%xn'  32")}' 
awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n'  32")}'
```

Why the two awk statements output same string?
We got more knowledges on shell expansions and quote removal.

[GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal)

> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters ‘\’, ‘'’, and ‘"’ 
>   that did not result from one of the above expansions are removed.

`awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%xn'  32")}' == awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n'  32")}'`  can be explained.

How about the following? 
What if many characters **`\`** ,more than one **`\`**

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\n'  32")}'
0sh: 2: 32: not found
```

Why not

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\n'  32")}'  ==  awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%xn'  32")}'
```

And more interesting ,let's to add more \ in it.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\\n'  32")}'
0sh: 2: 32: not found
```

To add four and five \s in it.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\\\n'  32")}'
20n$ awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\\\\n'  32")}'
20n$
```

Most most interesting thing here:

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\\\\\n'  32")}'
20$
```

character n lost and no newline.

Comment: if you really need to wrap `printf` with `system()`, you should say so, otherwise, calling `printf` like that is  unnecessary and redundant as `awk` has a built in `printf`. So. Just `awk 'BEGIN{printf ("%x\n", 32)}' /dev/null` should do. Good luck.

Comment: wrt `The right awk statement to call the above bash in awk is as below.` - no, it isn't. wrt the rest - I told you already (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43346862/1745001) that you can't include `'`s in a `'`-delimited script. What part of that statement is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>If the command at hand is more than just an example, it is worth heeding [shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter)'s helpful advice to use `awk`'s *built-in* `printf` function - there's no need to call `system()` with the *external* `printf` utility.

`awk 'BEGIN{ printf "%x\n", 32 }'` works just fine.</sup>

Overall, you have **3 layers of quoting** to deal with, in sequence:

- First, the current shell (`bash`) interprets the tokens of the command - both the quoted and unquoted ones.
- `awk` then sees the result of this interpretation and performs its own interpretation of the embedded double-quoted `printf` command string.
- The result is passed to `system()`, which invokes `/bin/sh`, where the string is again interpreted by the shell (`sh`, in this case).

#### Your *original* command:

`awk` is incidental to your first command; it is the *shell*'s (Bash's) string quoting that matters:

- POSIX-like shells such as Bash allow string concatenation by placing any mix of unquoted, single-quoted, and double-quoted (interpolated, expanded) strings directly next to each other.
- Single-quoted strings - `'...'` - do *not* support *nesting*.
- Therefore, `'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n'  32")}'` breaks down as:

  - `'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n'` - a single-quoted shell string whose contents are used as-is.
  - `%x\n`, an *unquoted* shell string that is subject to [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html):

    - `%x` is used as-is.
    - `\`-prefixing a character is a *character-individual form of quoting*: `\<char>` tells the shell that `<char>` is to be taken *literally*, so `\n` turns into plain `n`. This form of quoting is only required for shell metacharacters (characters such as `|` that normally have special meaning), and since `n` is not one of them, `\n` and `n` are effectively the same, so `%xn` - without the `\` - would result in the *same* literal.
  - `'  32")}'`,  a single-quoted shell string whose contents are used as-is.
- Thus, after expansions, which includes the removal of the quoting characters (`'` and `\` in this case, a process known as [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal)) and concatenation, the shell ultimately passes the following literal to `awk`:
  `BEGIN{system("printf %xn  32")}`
- As you can see, `awk` never sees the `\`.

  - Because Awk finds no escape sequences in string `"printf %xn  32"`, it passes literal `printf %xn  32` to the `system()` function, which in turn invokes `/bin/sh` with the specified string.
  - Thus, shell command `printf %xn  32` is executed, which prints `20n`, without a trailing newline.

    - Note that this command, due to being passed to `/bin/sh`, is again subject to shell expansions (in essentially the same way as in `bash`, except for process substitution and, potentially, Bash-specific parameter expansions), but they result in no change in this case.

#### Your *follow-up* questions:

Building on the explanations above:

`awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\n'  32")}'` results in the following literal `awk` script:

```
BEGIN{system("printf %x\n  32")}
```

`\\n`, from the shell's perspective, is `\\` - a quoted `\` character - followed by `n`, resulting in *literal* `\n`.

In this case, control-character escape sequence `\n` is interpreted by *Awk* and converted to an *actual* newline before the string is passed to `/bin/sh` by the `system()` function.

Thus, `/bin/sh` sees *two* commands:

```
printf %x
32
```

`printf %x` prints 0, because in the absence of an argument for format char. `%x` the value defaults to `0`.
`32` by itself is not a valid command, hence the error message `sh: 2: 32: not found` (`2` is the line number).

---

`awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\\n'  32")}'` is the same as the previous command:

`\\\n`, from the shell's perspective, is `\\` - a quoted `\` character - followed by `\n` - a quoted `n` character - again resulting in *literal* `\n`.

---

As for `awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\\\n'  32")}'`:

`\\\\n` results in literal `\\n`.

`awk` in turn interprets that as *literal* `\n`.

`/bin/sh` then again interprets that `\n` as an individually quoted `n` literal, effectively executing `printf %xn  32`, which yields `20n`, without a trailing newline.

---

As for `awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\\\\\\n'  32")}'`:

`awk` sees `\\\n`, which it turns into literal `\`, followed by an actual newline.
Therefore, what is ultimately passed to `/bin/sh` by `awk` looks like this:

```
printf %x\
  32
```

The above, which contains an `\`-escaped actual newline, is interpreted as a *single* command by `/bin/sh` (this is how line continuation works in the shell), so it is effectively the same as
`printf %x   32` and results in  `20`, without a trailing newline.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud write like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { system("printf \"%x\\n\" 32") }'
20
$ awk 'BEGIN { system("printf '\''%x\n'\'' 32") }'
20
$ awk 'BEGIN { system("printf '\''%x\\n'\'' 32") }'
20
$ awk $'BEGIN { system("printf \'%x\\n\' 32") }'
20
$
```

In Bash, your `'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n' 32")}'` is actually 3 separated strings concatenated into one:

```
1)  'BEGIN{system("printf '
2)  %x\n                     <-- this will become %xn
3)  ' 32")}'
```

so your command is actually `awk 'BEGIN{system("printf %xn 32")}'`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n' 32")}'
BEGIN{system("printf %xn 32")}
$ awk 'BEGIN{system("printf '%x\n' 32")}'
20n$ awk 'BEGIN{system("printf %xn 32")}'
20n$
```