# bash apend line within group of lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

*edited for clarification*
I have a file with content

```
Group1
LineA
LineB
LineC


Group2
LineA
LineB
LineC


Group3
LineA
LineB
LineC
```

and I want to insert a specific template at a group. Lets say I call a function like `insertAtGroup 2 D` so end result should be

```
Group1
LineA
LineB
LineC


Group2
LineA
LineB
LineC
LineD

Group3
LineA
LineB
LineC
```

I tried it with sed but I couldn't get that to work

Comment: This is a job for `awk` with RS set to the empty string.  Lots of documentation and examples available.

Comment: Unless you always insert at the end of a group, suggest review of [How to print ASCII value of a character using basic awk only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2499270/3422102)

Comment: Insert based on what? The relative line number within group 2, or the appearcnce of a specific string in that group? If that latter should that be a full string, partial string, full regexp or partial regexp match? Please [edi]t your question to show a more concrete example and to add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I was guessing the insert would check against the Group and Entry suffix, e.g. `substr($1, length($1))` but then that was just my read. Then if not always inserting at the end, a function to handle the lookup/map between ordinal and character was my thinking.

Comment: I would say what you want to do is _appending to a group_, not _inserting_. You might want to make this clear in the title and text of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this appends "LineD" to Group2, by specifying n and v variables.

```
  $ awk -v n=2 -v v="D" '$0=="Group"n {f=1} 
                         f&&!NF       {sub(/.$/,v,line); print line; f=0} 
                         f            {line=$0}1' file

Group1
LineA
LineB
LineC


Group2
LineA
LineB
LineC
LineD


Group3
LineA
LineB
LineC
```

assumes group names are unique and don't match the other lines.

Captures the last name from the group and replaces the last character with the given value and inserting at the first blank line.  The group name is matched by appending the given number to the "Group" prefix.

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up doing, thanks

Answer (score 1):

with perl using "paragraph mode"

```
perl -p00e 's/$/LineD\n/ if /^Group2/' file.txt
```

in case to inplace edit add `-i` flag

```
perl -i -p00e 's/$/LineD\n/ if /^Group2/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` and your example data:

```
sed '/Group2/,/^$/ s/^$/LineD/' inputfile
```